# SSRS: Expression to return Date Range in 'mm-dd-yyyy' format

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a *Variable* in my report that returns a String with a Date Range that looks like this: 02-01-2018 - 01-31-2019

I have tried this expression:

```
    =FormatDateTime(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), “1”).AddMonths(-12), DateFormat.ShortDate) 
    & " -  " &
    FormatDateTime(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), “1”).AddDays(-1))
```

and it gives me this: 2/1/2018 - 1/31/2019.

I cannot have /'s in the date range because I am using the Variable as the Page Name of the Tablix that will end up as the Sheet [Tab] name in Excel when I export the report. Excel does not seem to accept /'s in the Sheet Names.

In short, I need to be able to dynamically create a date range of 12 months ending at the last date of the previous month - and it should be a string that looks like 02-01-2018 - 01-31-2019.

Comment: @Dave Burrell. I notice that my questions are often Edited & I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong. I can't tell that your edit changed anything in what I posted. I'd appreciate your help in understanding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
= Today.AddDays(1-Today.Day).AddYears(-1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & " - " & Today.AddDays(-Today.Day).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang Kais. I appreciate your help. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VB.NET **.ToString** to convert to any format that you want.

```
=TODAY.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

So your string would be

```
=TODAY.AddMonths(-12).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & " - " & TODAY.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: Your expression works but today [02/05/2019] it does not take me back to Feb. 1, 2018 and Jan. 31, 2019. Instead, it gives me 02-05-2018 - 02-04-2019. If I always ran the report on the 1st of the month, it would work but my users may choose to run it on other days in the month. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your own date format to use:

```
=FormatDateTime(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), “1”).AddMonths(-12), "MM-dd-yyyy") 
& " -  " &
FormatDateTime(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), “1”).AddDays(-1), "MM-dd-yyyy")
```